# Django not serving media files if I check for settings.DEBUG

Tags: django, django-media

This serves the media files correctly:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This doesn't serve the media files:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [ ... ] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) writes "This is not suitable for production use!", so that is why I need a way to check for DEBUG before serving media files. How can I do that. Why does this approach doesn't work?

Comment: development server is running in one or two threads, so it's thruput is very limited, so you request are served one-by-one - slowly, plus each static file is being served using basic open-read-send-close operations, without any os advantages (e.g. sendfile, zero-copy) - check uwsgi - it is quite robust and works well with django

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

(notice '=' after '+' - in your version you are adding `static()` patterns but not assigning the result to the `urlpatterns` variable)